# Is there a common label.txt file for quantized TFLite image classification models?

Tags: tensorflow, label, tensorflow-lite, image-classification, tensorflow-hub

I have built an android ML image classification app using the starter model from Tensorflow.org/lite. The starter model includes the .TFLite model and also an accompanying label.txt file. I now want to try different ML models in this app. I have downloaded some inception and mobilenet models, but none of them come with an accompanying label.txt file. Does anyone know if there is a common label.txt file that I can use alongside any quantized ML model and if so where I can get a copy? or does my only label.txt file fit all? alternatively does anyone have any label.txt files for the inception ML models that they can share with me?

Answer (score 0):

Every line of the text file is a label of the model. So you can change the "labels" of the old label.txt file with your labels. You can search inside the starter code how you can use this file. Check also this [link](http://Hi,%20every%20line%20of%20the%20text%20file%20is%20a%20label%20of%20the%20model.%20So%20you%20can%20change%20the%20%22labels%22%20of%20the%20old%20label.txt%20file%20with%20your%20labels.%20You%20can%20search%20inside%20the%20code%20how%20you%20can%20use%20this%20file.%20Check%20also%20this%20link%20with%20the%20use%20of%20Support%20library%20to%20load%20the%20label.txt%20file%20https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support#optional_mapping_results_to_labels) with the use of Support library to load the label.txt file easily.

Use the dependency inside the app build.gradle file. (Check the versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-support))

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.3.0'
```

and inside your code:

```
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.FileUtil;

final String ASSOCIATED_AXIS_LABELS = "labels.txt";
List<String> associatedAxisLabels = null;

try {
   associatedAxisLabels = FileUtil.loadLabels(this, ASSOCIATED_AXIS_LABELS);
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("tfliteSupport", "Error reading label file", e);
}
```

If you need anything else ping me.

Best